# CPU (?) clicking sound during resource-intensive tasks

Tags: cpu, power-management, noise, intel-core-i7

I just bought a new computer (Lenovo Yoga 13, with integrated graphics and SSD).

Whenever I bring it out of sleep, or do something resource-intensive (such as heavy Photoshop work), I hear a scratchy ticking/clicking sound.  Similar to the sound of an old hard drive writing data... except this computer doesn't have a spinning hard drive.

Sounds similar to this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FdCKZ8qaUU

Is it the same problem?  Coil whine?  Coil whine has been noted for this machine by other users, and I believe I have a minor affliction of that as well.  But this sound is quite noticeable and not especially high-frequency.

I've read that Intel i*x* processors can produce this sound when they enter certain C-states.  Should I request an exchange/repair?  Would the new unit be any different (in other words, is this a defect or design flaw)?

If I choose to stick with this model of computer, must I just live with the noise?  Would disabling power-conserving C-states have a profound effect on battery life or processor longevity?

Comment: That would be surprising (but my wife's old laptop had some caps whine).  My guess would first be fan related since that is probably the only moving part in the laptop.  Any way for you to try to check that, maybe block it from spinning for long enough to check?

Comment: @nerdwaller - The down side of doing that is that if it's not the fan, you could potentially burn out the fan motor.  Holding the fan while current flows through the coils causes a huge amount of resistance which has to be dissipated as heat.  Not highly likely, but in the realm of possibility.  Since that would cause you to have to get it repaired, I might recommend having work done under warranty in this case?

Comment: @Everett - Yeah, I probably should have mentioned the possibility.  Thanks for pointing that out, though I am yet to ever see an issue since most are brushless and the polarity really shouldn't be affected.

Comment: @nerdwaller - I've seen it happen once in 2 decades, even working on computers that have been in sandy desert environments.  But since it's possible...  We have to tell people not to use a hairdryer in the tub and all that ;)

Comment: I'm certain it's not either of the primary fans.  It happens before the fans kick on and while they're running with no change.  From a different location as well.